# Log4j not working after Tomcat has Started

Tags: tomcat, logging, log4j

I have an application deployed on tomcat server and using log4j logging system. The application is hosted on centOS.

My question is - In my *ServletContextListener*, log4j logs messages I have instructed on console fine, but when tomcat has finally completed startup, log4j doesn't work any longer.

The strange thing is, this application is deployed on a UAT enviroment and log4j works fine.
The only difference been tomcat on UAT and tomcat on production is, I have some symbolic directories in my tomcat directory where webapps, bin etc.. are located.

Any idea why this issue?

```
<appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="com.el.app">
    <level value="warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="console" />
</logger>
```

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work any longer? Does it work in between? What does not working mean? Does it produce exception, logs errors or does nothing?

Comment: What is the code (java, xml or other) that you use for configuring log4j?

Comment: Yes it works in between.

Comment: I have also noticed Exceptions are not printed on console neigther.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if something else is trying to configure log4j or if there are two instances and you are using one during startup and later on a different instance. ClassLoader pop up.

What you could try is to run the tomcat with java -verbose:class . This should provide lots of logs about the classes loaded. Check if any logging stuff gets loaded more then once, or if there are other logging libraries getting loaded.

Another test is to remove all your log4j setup. Log4j should now complain about not being setup properly. If it doesn't I'd say something else is configuring it in ways not anticipated.

You can check if Log4J offers any hooks to inform you about changes in the configuration.

Finally you might debug into a call to log4j to see where you message gets swallowed.